# C#: Problems with switch statement?

Tags: c#, listbox, switch-statement

This is the code for my project where you select an item in a listbox, and a picture along with a description will pop up.

```
        fruitBox = new ListBox();
        fruitImage = new PictureBox();

        fruitBox.Items.Add("Mangosteen");
        fruitBox.Items.Add("Bael");
        fruitBox.Items.Add("Coffee Berries");
        fruitBox.Items.Add("Jujube");
        fruitBox.Items.Add("Durian");

        string selectedFruit;


    }

    private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedFruit;
        selectedFruit = fruitBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (fruitBox.SelectedIndex == -1)

        {
            selectedFruit = fruitBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

            switch (selectedFruit)
            {

                case "Mangosteen":
                    fruitImage.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
                    fruitDescription.Text = "Mangosteen description";
                    break;

                case "Bael":
                    fruitImage.Image = imageList1.Images[1];
                    fruitDescription.Text = "Bael description";
                    break;

                case "Durian":
                    fruitImage.Image = imageList1.Images[2];
                    fruitDescription.Text = "Durian description";
                    break;

                case "Coffee Berries":
                    fruitImage.Image = imageList1.Images[3];
                    fruitDescription.Text = "Coffee Berries description";
                    break;

                case "Jujube":
                    fruitImage.Image = imageList1.Images[4];
                    fruitDescription.Text = "Jujube description";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select a fruit");
```

But when I try to run it, this message pops up:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Exotic Fruits.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You should delete this line, before your if statement:

```
selectedFruit = fruitBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

`fruitBox.SelectedItem` might be **null** if there is no `SelectedItem`.You are checking the `SelectedIndex` but before you try to access `SelectedItem` and that makes your if statement *pointless*.And also you can change your `if` statement like this:

```
if(fruitBox.SelectedItem != null)
```

Comment: Also... if `SelectedIndex == -1`... you're gonna be null. Maybe that should be `!= -1` ... ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I think this is more safe :) `if(fruitBox.SelectedItem != null)` But you right too.